# What's the use of "user referenced this issue from a commit in repository" in GitHub issues?

Tags: github, github-issues

I have a bunch of entries that say "*someone* referenced this issue from a commit in *someone/project*" that are automatically inserted by GitHub in the comments of a reported issue.

[image: ref this issue]

These are not pull requests, so what are they useful for?

Moreover, some of them are orphan commits, that appear repeatedly when someone forces a push to GitHub. Can they be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're useful in allowing you to [cross-reference from one repository to another](https://github.com/blog/1439-closing-issues-across-repositories), so that comments or issues raised elsewhere can link back and have a point of context in a way.

They're also good for those who want to use GitHub as [an issue tracker for the public, who you don't want to see your source code](https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions/).

For example, you have a public repo that only allows users to open Issues. And linked with that you have a private repo where the code actually sits among your team. If you push a fix, you can close the public Issue tracker and that reference will show the context/reason.

This is also part of [a social coding aspect](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets), where you can have other forks and repos reference each other to create some kind of group focus.

You cannot currently stop this cross-linking behaviour.